# FragmentPagerAdapter getItem() displaying position 1 instead of 0

Tags: android, fragmentpageradapter

I've has a look at majority of the answers here and can't find something that works for me.

I have a fragment called ActiveThreads I want it to be that whenever the user clicks on an item on this page it loads a pagerActivity which uses a FragmentPagerActivity where the user can scroll.

The issue I'm having is that when I click on one item it shows the NEXT item instead. I was running through it with debug and it calls the current position and then the next position. However it shows the next position first and not the first? Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Code for PostPager Activity's getItem method

```
private void populateUIWithData() {
    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    mViewPager.setAdapter(new FragmentPagerAdapter(fragmentManager) {
        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            if (mThreadItems != null){
                mThreads = mThreadItems.get(position);
                mFragment = PostFragment.newInstance(mThreads.getId(), mThreads.getTopic_name(),
                        mThreads.getName(), mThreads.getNum_posts());
                mViewPager.getCurrentItem();
            }
            return mFragment;
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return mThreadItems.size();
        }

        @Override
        public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
            if (object != null) {
                return ((Fragment) object).getView() == view;
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        }
    });
}
```

and here's my new instance in PostFragment

```
public static PostFragment newInstance(String threadID, String topicName, String threadName, String postCount) {
    mThreadID = threadID;
    mTopicName = topicName;
    mThreadName = threadName;
    mPostCount = postCount;

    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putSerializable("threadID", threadID);
    args.putSerializable("topicName", topicName);
    args.putSerializable("threadName", threadName);
    args.putSerializable("postCount", postCount);

    mCurrentFragment = new PostFragment();

    mCurrentFragment.setArguments(args);

    return mCurrentFragment;
}
```

**EDIT** here's the code for active threads when I press on an item

```
   private void initUI() {
    mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) mRootView.findViewById(R.id.threadRecyclerView);
    mLayoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(getActivity(), 1);
    mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
    mSwipeRefreshLayout = (SwipeRefreshLayout) mRootView.findViewById(R.id.swipeForNewThreads);
    mSwipeRefreshLayout.setColorSchemeResources(R.color.blue, R.color.green, R.color.yellow, R.color.red);

    mSwipeRefreshLayout.setOnRefreshListener(new SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener() {
        @Override
        public void onRefresh() {
            loadNewData();
        }
    });

    mRecyclerView.addOnItemTouchListener(new RecyclerItemClickListener
            (getActivity(), new RecyclerItemClickListener.OnItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemClick(View view, int position) {
                    showItemSelectedAtPosition(position);

                }
            }));
    loadData();

}

private void loadNewData() {

    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            loadData();
            mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            mSwipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);
        }
    }, 0);

}

private void loadData() {

    mDataFactory = new ThreadFeedDataFactory(getActivity());
    mDataFactory.getActiveThreadFeed(new ThreadFeedDataFactory.ThreadFeedDataFactoryCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onThreadDataReceived(ThreadResponse response) {
            mData = response;
            populateUIWithData();

        }

        @Override
        public void onThreadDataFailed(Exception exception) {

        }
    });

}

private void populateUIWithData() {


    mAdapter = new ThreadAdapter(getActivity(), mData);
    mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
}

private void showItemSelectedAtPosition(int position) {
    Threads selectedThread = mData.getItem(position);

    Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), PostPagerActivity.class);
    intent.putExtra("Threads", Parcels.wrap(selectedThread.getThreadItem()));

    startActivity(intent);

}
```

Look at the showSelectedItemOnPosition method, this is where I load the PostPagerActivity OnClick. Any ideas?

**EDIT** From my log cat

```
05-03 10:47:54.857 7894-7894/com.mumsnet.android E/threadItemID: 2628772
05-03 10:47:54.865 7894-7894/com.mumsnet.android E/POSTFRAG: threadItemID: 2628772
05-03 10:47:54.867 7894-7894/com.mumsnet.android E/threadItemID: 2628697
05-03 10:47:54.867 7894-7894/com.mumsnet.android E/POSTFRAG: threadItemID: 2628697
05-03 10:47:54.916 7894-7894/com.mumsnet.android E/LoadData: threadItemID: 2628697
05-03 10:47:54.925 7894-7894/com.mumsnet.android E/LoadData: threadItemID: 2628697
```

Can you see the id changes? It's displaying the items related to the second ID! :(

Thanks in advance

Comment: Hi, please include the code for `ActiveThreads` - since this is where you say you call the `pagerActivity` - we can examine the code to figure out why it behaves as you say.

Comment: @ishmaelMakitla done

Comment: Please add the Log statement in the `showItemSelectedAtPosition(int position)` to show what is the value of `position`. Confirm if this is as you expect - for instance does selecting item at first position showing value of `1` for `position`? This might shed some light on this.

Comment: @ishmaelMakitla posted some of my log cat at the bottom for you

Comment: Can you try something like this:  `mThreads = mThreadItems.get(mViewPager.getCurrentItem());` and see if this works as you expect.

Comment: This does exactly what I wanted to do thank you! Do you want to post this as an answer and I'll vote it? @ishmaelMakitla

Answer (score 0):

It seems your mThreadItems.get(position); returns the wrong object.

Comment: It gets the right object then gets the second object and that's what gets passed through

Comment: but this is a normal behavior. The current and the next fragment is loaded, but in two different getItem calls. Normally Android would call getItem twice, you should check that with logcat.

I think your implementation is wrong. Maybe using global members is the thing that corrupts your fragment creation. A cleaner way is to use a new class as an adapter instead of using a inner class.

Comment: Ok, how would I get around this problem?

Comment: sorry accidently posted just a part of the message, now I added the rest